# subtracting days from a given day in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Personal leave is 10 days. I need the remaining leave to be subtracted from the total personal leave i.e 10 days

[result i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABaOq.jpg)

```
   SELECT id, firstname,lastname,join_date, completion_date,title, leave_from,leave_to, Given_leave_Days,Taken_Leave_Days,Remaining_Leave_Days  FROM (SELECT T1.id,T1.firstname,T1.lastname,T1.join_date,T1.completion_date,T0.title,T2.leave_from,T2.leave_to,T2.user_id,T0.Leave_Days as Given_leave_Days,SUM(DATEDIFF(T2.leave_to,T2.leave_from)+1) AS Taken_Leave_Days ,T0.Leave_Days - SUM(DATEDIFF(T2.leave_to,T2.leave_from)+1) as 'Remaining_Leave_Days' FROM users_leave_request T2 INNER JOIN users T1 ON T2.user_id = T1.id INNER JOIN leave_type T0 ON T2.leave_type_id = T0.id GROUP BY T1.id, T1.firstname, T1.lastname, T1.join_date,T1.completion_date,T0.title,T2.leave_from,T2.leave_to,Given_leave_Days order by firstname) A
```

i have to display the result in frontend.

[result in frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxMDI.jpg)

Comment: If you want to modify the database fields, you're doing that all wrong. Modifying is done using `UPDATE`, not `SELECT`. Try looking online for that, show us some effort of (at least) trying to solve it, then if it still doesn't work, or you have any problem, come back here and you'll get helped

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is

```
select date_sub(now(), interval 10 day)
```

You can replace `now()` for any date from a table, you can change `day` for `month`, `year`, etc.

The result from my example is a date 10 days before today. For example, if you want to filter only the dates older than 10 days you would do like this:

```
select * from mytable t where t.mydate < date_sub(now(), interval 10 day)
```

Comment: I wrote a general answer that will help you and people coming from google search looking for general answers. If you want me to fix your sql statement to your specific scenario, please format it a little bit with line breaks so I can understand it.